# How to read data from Redis cache and query it in Java?

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I am new to redis cache i am using core or plain java not spring boot to interact with redis cache. I am able to connect to redis cache using the jedis client but not getting how to retrieve the data using combination of two keys i found a way in spring boot like below but i am unable to find the same in plain java please point me some source where i am unable to find any instructions in redis documentation also around this

```
@Cacheable(value = "items", key = "#id")
public Item getItem(Integer id) {
    Item item = itemRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
    logger.info("Loading data from DB {}", item);
    return item;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

On plain java, create a RedisTemplate object and then, use it to query your information.

```
public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration config = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(host, port);
    config.setUsername(username);
    config.setPassword(password);
    config.setDatabase(db);
    return new JedisConnectionFactory(config);
}


public RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<?, ?> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    template.setKeySerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<String>(String.class));
    template.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    return template;
}
```

For example

`redisTemplate.opsForValue().add("key", "value")`

Answer (score 2):

I am using this way to read data from Redis cache:

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Cacheable(value = "users", key = "#userId", unless = "#result.followers < 12000")
@RequestMapping(value="/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User getUser(@PathVariable String userId) {
  LOG.info("Getting user with ID {}.", userId);
  return userRepository.findOne(Long.valueOf(userId));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i am looking something in core java not in spring boot

Comment: In java you add Jedis Dependency
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version> <!-- Check for the latest version on Maven Central -->
</dependency>